# Keras custom class_weight with multi output

Tags: networking, keras

Regarding Neural Networks and Keras, in the past when I had only 1 node with 0 / 1 output and unbalanced classes, I defined:

```
class_weight = {0: .1 , 1: .14}
```

and then used that dictionary in the .fit function.

What is the equivalent of that dictionary if now I am dealing with outputs [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `{0: w0, 1: w1, 2: w2}`?

Comment: Yes, but how do I know that 0 -> [1,0,0], 1 -> [0,1,0], 2 -> [0,0,1]? Does that depends in the order that they appear in the dataset?

Comment: That's the standard conversion when you use `to_categorical`, for instance. 0 is [1,0,0]; 1 is [0,1,0]; 2 is [0,0,1].

Comment: Ohhh didn't know that! Many thanks!